# KendoUI DropDownList server filtering

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui

I have datagrid with filters, but in addition to those i want to add dropdownlist
 with ready data items to filter by, how to do it in kendoway?
How to POST category name to server with picked value?

```
  $("#category_list").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataSource: {
          transport: {
            read: {
              url: '/api/notes/cats',
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'GET',
            },
          },
          schema: {
            data: function(reply) {
              return reply.rows
            },
          }
    },
    change: function() {
      val = $("#category_list").val();

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, then you want your DropDownList to have pre-made filters that get applied to your Grid?

In the `click` event of your DropDown, you can get the Grid's `DataSource` and apply a filter to it using the `.filter()` function.

Something like:

```
$("#category_list").kendoDropDownList({
    change: function() {
        var grid = $("#my_grid").data().kendoGrid;
        var filters = grid.dataSource.filters;

        // modify filters as needed

        grid.dataSource.filter(filters);
    }
 });
```